# How to add images to a website from a folder on server

Tags: php

I am a beginner in web developing . I have succesfully moved images from my folder to a hostinger folder under public_html ,now i need to display those images in the gallery of the website.how can i do that using php ,my folder name is uploads .?

Comment: Where is your code that you have tried?

Comment: can you explain that with a complete code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop over images in that directory and echo them in your page:

```
$dir = "/uploads";
//get the list of all files with .jpg extension in the directory and safe it in an array named $images
$images = glob( $dir );

//extract only the name of the file without the extension and save in an array named $find
foreach( $images as $image ):
    echo "<img src='" . $image . "' />";
endforeach;
```

Comment: So is not a code community. Please avoid answers that are related to delivering full code!